# Skip a download in terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, sudo, gnome-terminal

I am downloading four files (8gb each), I already have 2nd files and i don't want to download it again. How can i just skip it. I don't want to cancel the download as it will cancel the 3rd and 4th download as well and if i restart it'will download the 1st file again.

Comment: How are you "downloadingc the files? `wget` has  the `--continue` option to do this. Read `man wget`.

Comment: If you're using curl, use the `-C` option. [man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-C)